# C# Web Application Smart Card Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, iis-7, smartcard

I have a C# web application (IIS 7.0) and I have Smart Card Authentication set up on the site.  The user is required to have a Client Certificate associated to their account which allows them to login.  Now I want to go a step further and either after 15 minutes of inactivity on the site, or if the user logs out, I want to website to redirect to a logged out state and a page specifically designed as a log out page. This all works fine, now is the tricky part.

Now, if the user is at the logged out page and wants to log in again, they must select a link to log in again, and I want IIS to ask the user to select their cert again and input their pin (smart card), how do I force IIS to do this?  I would imagine that on the logged out page I need to somehow dump the user cert so that when the user logs in (default.aspx) the system will ask for their cert, but I do not know how to do this, is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried?  Most of the time this is actually left up to Windows to determine if the certification needs the pin again.

Comment: @Ramhound I have tried setting a timeout in IIS to see if that worked.  I have also looked at some code snippits to try and force my application to ask again, but both were unsuccessful